# .net 4.6 and GC freeze

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-4.6

I had a serious problem with the performance one of my projects after installing .net 4.6. It reproduced in the following case when the program is mass data processing and large amount of memory allocated about 4 gigabytes at some point the process stops responding and that the procedure performed for about 90 seconds performed for 30-40 minutes. If I try to stop, the process under debugging, visual studio freeze also and did not show the thread call stacks. At the same time when attach to a hung process to see the call stacks, which can see that the process hangs on the memory allocation, the stack below.

Stack of the main thread:

```
WKS::gc_heap::allocate_in_older_generation
clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_in_older_generation()
clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::plan_phase()
clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::gc1()
clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect()
clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration()
clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space() 
clr.dll!JIT_New() 
00007ffc1a87f061()
00007ffc1a87c2a0()
00007ffc1a87c3d8()
00007ffc189c8b3b()
WindowsBase.ni.dll!00007ffc75b917e3()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for WindowsBase.ni.dll]    .
```

The problem is not reproduce on computers without .net 4.6. In addition, the problem not reproduced if I set the application flag gcServer or launch an application from the ANST Memory Profiler, which is very strange.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does [this 4.6 GC issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2015/08/12/gen2-free-list-changes-in-clr-4-6-gc.aspx) match up?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is it.

Comment: Since which clr version is it fixed? I have seen such stack with 4.6.96.0

Comment: Now I do not see this problem. I installed .net Framework 4.6.1, mscorlib.dll has version 4.6.1055.0.